# How to persist an ifconfig setting on macOS

Tags: networking, macos

I run this command on startup `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.254.254.254`. How do I get this to persist after reboot on macOS?

Comment: found this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2005012202111996 - but the basics are that /etc/rc.common is where you'd go on OSX for what is set at boot for network config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution at http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2005012202111996 is not current any more and doesn't work on OSX >10.4. The Macworld site doesn't allow edits any more.

To make this a startup script, try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
# Created by Roland Giesler, 5/2/2017
#
# Shell script to set IP address aliases on the Ethernet port
# Change the port to match your desired interface
#

/sbin/ifconfig en7 alias 172.16.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Now use the instructions on https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT2420 to create a Login Hook that runs this script when the user logs in.
Since this only runs at login, there's no need for the tests to see if the alias exists.